# Make Google Translator Widget Language Labels in English rather than user's browser language

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I am using a google translator widget on my website. Script below.

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

The translation widget comes up and language switching works fine.

But the problem is that the text in google widget drop-down is getting loaded in the browser language.

For example, if I open the website from Netherlands/Dutch, it will show **Engels** instead of **English**

What I need is to display the widget text always in English.

I did try adding the **Pagelaguage** as 'en' but didn't work.

Need help to solve this.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773687/google-translate-set-default-language?rq=1

Comment: @Amitd: this is not what I was asking for. I need the translator widget text to be displayed in English all the time.